# Understand a function within Hermes byte code

Tags: decompilation, android, byte-code

The Android app I am looking at uses React Native with the [Hermes JS Engine](https://hermesengine.dev/). This generates a `index.android.bundle` binary that contains Hermes JS bytecode.

I was able to disassemble the binary file using [hbctool](https://github.com/niosega/hbctool/tree/draft/hbc-v84) and came across a function that I would like to learn more about e.g. `getSecretData`

```
CreateClosure           Reg8:1, Reg8:1, UInt16:9784
PutById                 Reg8:2, Reg8:1, UInt8:3, UInt16:25656
; Oper[3]: String(25656) 'getSecretData'
```

This function doesn't appear in any of the `*.so` files placed in the APK lib folder as I checked with a simple `nm` command:

```
for FILE in *.so; do nm -D $FILE | grep secret; done
```

Using [frida](https://frida.re/docs/android/) to list all the Java classes just lists the ones I already have access to via the `classes.dex` file:

```
Java.enumerateLoadedClasses({
    onMatch: function(className) {
        console.log(className);
    },
    onComplete: function() {}
});
```

There is talk of a "[show source](https://github.com/facebook/hermes/issues/114#issuecomment-887106990)" directive that has been added to Hermes compiler so I am not sure if this is something that can be injected in.

Any help on how I can explore further will be greatly appreciated.